# Filtrar un solo resultado en dominio

Tags: python, mvc, odoo

En uno de los popup que estoy haciendo, hice un abstractmodel para que busque por fecha de creacion y por nombre pero esta para que busque de una persona en especifico pero al meter el nombre lo que hace es que me imprime todos los registros  y no los registros que solo esten con su nombre

Adjunto codigo:

````
```import json
   import io
   import calendar
   from datetime import timedelta, datetime
   from dateutil import rrule

   from reportlab.platypus.tableofcontents import delta
   from xlsxwriter import workbook

    from odoo.tools import date_utils
    from odoo import fields, models, api


   try:
from odoo.tools.misc import xlsxwriter
except ImportError:
import xlsxwriter


class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
_name = "sale_report_executive"

date_order = fields.Date(string="Fecha de cotizacion")
seller_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='hr.employee',string='Ejecutivo')
def get_executive_report(self):
    data = {
        'date_order': self.date_order,
        'seller_id': self.seller_id,
    }
    return self.env.ref('sale_report_terrestre.action_ejecutivo_report').report_action(self, data=data)


class executivecard(models.AbstractModel):
_name = 'report.sale_report_terrestre.sales_executive_view'

@api.model
def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
    return {
        'doc_ids': docids,
        'doc_model': 'sale.order',
        'docs': self.env['sale.order'].search_read([('date_order', '>=', data['date_order']),
                                                    ('seller_id', '!=', data['seller_id'])],
                                                   ['name', 'seller_id','date_order', 'consignee_id', 'country_arrival', "freight_type", "gross_weight", "volume","invoice_amount_assured",'partner_id']),
        'data':data
    }```
````

asi es como esta estructurado el modelo y la finalidad es que si yo meto un nombre en el campo de seller_id filtre todos los registros que estan con el nombre que se busca e iprima el reporte pero el error que esta haciendo es que esta imprimiendo todos los registros de todos los usuarios y en el encabezado del reporte pone el nombre del usuario que se este buscando y solo quiero que arroje los registros de ese usuario y no de todos

Comment: Según tu dominio `('seller_id', '!=', data['seller_id'])` estas filtrando todo lo que no sea igual a `data['seller_id']`. Si quieres lo que sea igual, debe ser `=`

Comment: a ok es que si lo pongo que fuilte lo que sea igual a data seller_id lo maanda vacio le agregue para que igual filtre por rango de fechas y si manda la informacion pero manda todos los rejistros y solo deberian de estar los registros del nombre que se ponga en el seller_id

Comment: Que contiene `data['seller_id']`? Si es todo el registro deberías pasar solo el id así: `data['seller_id'].id`

Comment: seller id es el campo donde estan los nombres de los empleados  seller_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='hr.employee',string='Ejecutivo')  y ahi vienen los nombres de todos los empleados y la finalidad es que me aparezcan solo los registros qu ehay echo x empleado en un rango de fechas

Comment: `('seller_id', '=', data['seller_id'].id)` intenta así.

Comment: File "/opt/odoo14.0/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 939, in _get_rendering_context
    data.update(report_model._get_report_values(docids, data=data))
  File "/opt/odoo14.0/odoo/customs_addons/o14-com-mti/sale_report_terrestre/wizard/sale_executive.py", line 65, in _get_report_values
    ('seller_id', '=', data['seller_id'].id)],
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

manda ese error

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141304/discussion-between-carlos-baez-and-legna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como estas tomando los campos desde un many2One y comparandolo con otro, Debes de utilizar el id para el dominio. De esta manera:

```py
    data = {
            'date_order': self.date_order,
            'seller_id': self.seller_id.id,
        }
```